# How can Spider-Man watch himself fighting with Ant-Man in the trailer of Spider-Man Homecoming?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, trailers, spider-man-homecoming

In the trailer of *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, Peter Parker is seen watching the video of himself fighting with Ant-Man in the movie *Captain America Civil War*.

How's that possible as there are apparently no cameras in that scene set up by someone else?

[image]

Is this possible that Peter had actually set up cameras to record those fight scenes? But this was never shown in the movie *Captain America Civil War.* Nor there was any scope. What is the explanation for this?

Comment: I haven't seen the trailer, but the simplest explanation I could come up with is the airport security camera.

Comment: Perhaps he rented the movie, or purchased the Blu-Ray?

Comment: Considering that dimensional breaches appear to be commonplace in Marvel, and that a multiverse is purported to exist (as it does in the comics), it is entirely possible that Tony Stark provided Peter with a DVD or Blu-Ray of *Captain America: Civil War*, which he obtained by reaching into the next universe over, where the Marvel Universe is simply considered a media property. We won't know for certain until *Spider-Man: Homecoming* arrives in theaters.

Comment: A longer version of this scene was shown at Comic-Con a couple of months ago. Back then it was [described as](http://io9.gizmodo.com/weve-seen-the-first-footage-from-spider-man-homecoming-1784197623): _"Peter Parker is sitting in class with his laptop, __watching a YouTube clip__ of himself fighting Giant Man from Civil War"_, [and:](http://www.slashfilm.com/spider-man-homecoming-news/) _"Peter watching __bystander footage__ of the airport battle from Civil War __on YouTube__"_.

Comment: @Oliver_C WHy don't you make it into an answer

Comment: @AnkitSharma because we get full aerial shots of the airport and know there are no bystanders on the tarmac? Because the shots are done at angles impossible for a fixed camera or people to be standing on? Because they explicitly say the airport was evacuated?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any number of reasons.

1. Iron Man and War Machine. The suits have cameras as seen in IM3 remote control flight.
2. Spider suit has mechanical lenses. Likely a camera, thanks to Stark Tech.
3. Airport security cameras.
4. Any number of spy satellites monitoring the fight, including Stark satellites.
5. **Parker set up cameras**. <-- once the movie released, we found the answer.
6. Hank Pym had spy ants set up.
7. Fury had better cameras around.
8. Falcon has a camera in his headset. And in Red Wing, his drone.
9. Black Panther suit likely has cameras.
10. I'd be shocked if Vision can't record or upload.
11. Suspension of disbelief and the typical use of non-realistic video footage of previous movies. The in universe explanation is hand waved.

Answer (score 7):

Airports do have copious amounts of security cameras, as DForck42 suggests.

Also, Peter Parker (in previous movies and the comics) has an established habit of setting up (photographic) cameras to capture pictures of himself as Spiderman that he can sell to his newspaper.  In fact, in some Spiderman continuities, this is how he first earns his position as a freelance photographer, and thus makes a living for himself. So, it's not outside the realm of suspension of belief that he did actually set up a video camera or two to film himself fighting in Civil War.  Strung up in otherwise improbable positions with webbing, naturally.

Comment: Airport do not have high res cameras without overlays laying in the middle of the tarmac or floating in the air.

Comment: I think we will have to wait and see the movie to know if Parker puts cameras around at this age, because he does that for pictures for his work at Daily Bugle. However, for this universe, he is just a teen in school.

Answer (score 7):

It was revealed in Spider-man Homecoming's first scene of Peter:

Peter himself shown obsession with vloging and recording it himself, he must have edited it and uploaded it on YouTube.

<sub>Note: But Peter was unaware that his suit had ability to record everything too which he got to know about later.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Its revealed in the intro of Spider-Man Homecoming. He's making a vlog.

Comment: I haven't seen the new one but it would also be consistent with the animated series and other historical material that show him "capturing" Spidey as Peter by "webbing" the cameras on a timer, and even at some point it was shown he needed a better camera to avoid blurring and also allow him to "remote shoot" when the "scene is right", implication being also that he switched from old film camera to some kind of digital camera

Comment: I think you should put a SPOILER tag buddy.

Comment: @Sand spoiler, photographer Peter Parker takes pictures. Since 1960 something. Shocking.

Comment: @cde In this case, where he is revealing what the intro of the spider-man homecoming movie, it is of course a spoiler. and OP wouldn't have asked this question if he had seen the movie himself. So it is a spoiler for him.